# Why is Head component not giving any output in DOM in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make the `<Head>` component work, but it doesn't give any results in the DOM.

Here is my `page.js`:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
    <Head>
      <title>
        Home
      </title>
    </Head>
    <main>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Below is `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

And below is my `layout.js`:

```js
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I've tried searching for solutions over the Internet and ChatGPT but nothing really helped. I have tried adding `Head` from `next/document` in `layout.js` and adding `<Head>` in `RootLayout` but importing `next/document` gave an error `Error: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function`, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the new App Router (Next.js 13 or more) *not* the old Pages Router, I guess you can't use `next/head` anymore. As far as I see it's a part of the [migration from Pages Router to App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#step-3-migrating-nexthead):

> ##### Step 3: Migrating next/head
>
> In the `pages` directory, the `next/head` React component is used to
> manage `<head>` HTML elements such as `title` and `meta`. In the app
> directory, `next/head` is replaced with the new [built-in SEO support](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata).
>
> Before in `pages/index.tsx`:
>
> ```
> import Head from 'next/head'
>
> export default function Page() {
>  return (
>    <>
>      <Head>
>        <title>My page title</title>
>      </Head>
>   </>
>  )
> }
> ```
>
> After in `app/page.tsx`:
>
> ```
> import { Metadata } from 'next'
>
> export const metadata: Metadata = {
>  title: 'My Page Title',
> }
>  
> export default function Page() {
>  return '...'
> }
> ```
>
> [See all metadata options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata).

Since it's going to be deprecated, it's better to use the new [built-in SEO support](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) which is called "Metadata".

Answer (score 0):

Just as an fyi, the OP used `JS` **NOT** `TS`, hence `page.js`,! Here's a code snippet for JS that I use on my website:

```
export const metadata = {
    title: 'home | 9662e',
}

export default function Home() {
    return (
       <>
           <div>some stuff on your page</div>
       </>
    )
}
```

You will not need to import anything, and you can remove the original metadata section in the layout.js(x).

Hope this helps anyone using JS!

**Signed**, 9662e103-129a